# Detecting iBeacons on iOS without supplying the UUID

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, beacon, altbeacon

I am making a react native app which monitors in background and killed state and ranges for beacons in foreground. I need to monitor more than 20 unique UUID region, to distinguish. Is there a way to monitor for beacons keeping uuid as null so it detects every beacon and then range to find uuid and send to server?

Answer (score 2):

No, you must specify at least the UUID when defining a beacon region to monitor and there is a limit of 20 regions.

If you know approximately which geographic region contains which beacons that you are interested in then you could combine location services with beacon monitoring; changing the set of beacon regions based on the current geographic location.